# Convert Multiple Videos to Multiple GIFs

Tags: video, conversion, animation, gif

What command will convert multiple video files to multiple GIFs?

I use the following command to convert 1 video to GIF:

`ffmpeg -i input.flv -vf scale=320:-1 output.gif`

I assume I'll need a bash script or some command with loop.

[This thread](https://superuser.com/questions/818017/convert-mutiple-gifs) is vaguely related to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following command

```
for f in ./*.flv; do
    ffmpeg -i "$f" -vf scale=320:-1 "${f%.*}.gif"
done
```

This iterates over all files ending with `.flv` in the current directory, processing them and changing the extension to `.gif`.

Note that the file names must not contain spaces for this to work.

Alternatively, on a GNU system, you can use

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.flv" -print0 |
  sed 's/\.flv\x00/\x00/g' |
  xargs -r0 -I FILENAME ffmpeg -i FILENAME.flv -vf scale=320:-1 FILENAME.gif
```

This will find all files ending with `.flv` (including hidden ones) in the current directory and print that list to the standard output as a `\0`-delimited string. That string is then filtered through `sed` to remove the extensions and then passed to `xargs` which executes the command `ffmpeg -i FILENAME.flv -vf scale=320:-1 FILENAME.gif`, replacing `FILENAME` by the actual file name from the list.

If you want to convert all files in the current directory and all sub-directories (and their sub-directories and so on), just remove the `-maxdepth 1` part from the command.

Comment: Unless your files contain newline characters, `sed` will only see one record which means storing the whole file list in memory and starting the processing only after `find` has finished crawling the directory. With a recent GNU `sed`, you could use `sed -z 's/\.flv$//'` instead.